# What is a good C# ASP.NET MVC question to ask a prospective employee?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am about to employ a new programmer for our ASP.NET MVC projects. I put a lot of weight in an interview as to just how much I like a candidate's attitude and how I see them working with, talking to and enjoying being part of the team, but on a more practical note  I need to weedle out those who talk a good game from those who actually have ability to adapt and overcome programming problems day to day.

Can anyone suggest any good short questions/exercises (preferably in C#) to separate the smart candidates from the good talkers?

UPDATE - Many thanks to all who answered, I have chosen the most voted for in traditional StackOverlfow manner, but still thanks for all the other suggestions.

Comment: At our company we just drop them into our Labyrinth and see how (and if) they defeat the Minotaur.  If you don't have a Labyrinth and Minotaur, substitute a large burlap sack and an angry panther.

Comment: Burlap?  Wow, your company must be rich!  We have to make due with second hand plastic bags from 7/11, not to mention our panther is actually a rather underfed gerbil.

Comment: "would you like to work from home?" - well, that's what I'd like to hear if I get any interviews for MVC work in the near future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first. Do they even know what MVC. Not just the TLA (three letter acronym) but can they describe it to you. Then what are the benefits. Also it doesn't hurt to ask them their opinion on it. It is good to know if they even like MVC frameworks.

Next, ask them if they have used any other MVC frameworks. Struts, Spring MVC, Zend or anything like that.

Ask them if they know when a session starts, the general state problem on the net etc etc.

Also a little bit of database. Ask them if they have any experience with database persistence layers.

Then just because you can ask a hard technical question, ask them to write a function that compares two binary trees both in value and structure to see if they are identicial.

Comment: Nice answer, apart from the hard technical question. One can be a highly skilled web developer and user of ASP.NET MVC without necessarily being able to write that function. It's not a bad thing to be able to it, but I would not discard people because they can't compare two binary trees.

Comment: No certainly not. But you want to be able to see how they think. If they get stuck then you can prod them along in the right direction. See if they can get to any answer. Forcing people to think is a very good way to see what type of problem solver they are. I find these types of questions show you who is a coder and who is lying.

Answer (score 23):

Which letter from MVC acronym should be responsible for performing the following features in online shop web application:

- calculating the total amount to pay for items in cart (M)
- build an html table of items to purchase (V)
- redirecting not authenticated users to the page where they can enter billing information (C)

etc.

Comment: good question I like it!

Answer (score 10):

Questions Which may be asked in ASP.Net MVC Interview.

1- what is ASP.Net MVC?

2- What is Razor?

3- What is TDD?

4- What is BDD?

5- What is Dependency Injection (DI)?

6- What is ViewData and ViewBag?

7- In which assembly is the MVC framework defined?

8- What does Model, View and Controller represent in an MVC application?

9- What are the advantages of ASP.NET MVC?

10- Which approach provides better support for test driven development - ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Webforms?

11- Name of different return types of a controller action method?

12- What is the significance of NonActionAttribute?

13- Is it possible to share a view across multiple controllers?

14- What is the role of a controller in an MVC application?

15- Where are the routing rules defined in an asp.net MVC application?

16- What are the 3 segments of the default route, that is present in an ASP.NET MVC application?

17- ASP.NET MVC application, makes use of settings at 2 places for routing to work correctly. What are these 2 places?

18- What is the adavantage of using ASP.NET routing?

19- What are the 3 things that are needed to specify a route?

20- What is the use of the following default route?

21- What is the difference between adding routes, to a webforms application and to an mvc application?

22- How do you handle variable number of segments in a route definition?

23- What are the 2 ways of adding constraints to a route?

24- Give 2 examples for scenarios when routing is not applied?

25- What is the use of action filters in an MVC application?

26- If I have multiple filters impleted, what is the order in which these filters get executed?

27- What are the different types of filters, in an asp.net mvc application?

28-Give an example for Authorization filters in an asp.net mvc application?

29- Which filter executes first in an asp.net mvc application?

30- What are the levels at which filters can be applied in an asp.net mvc application?

31- Is it possible to create a custom filter?

32- What filters are executed in the end?

33- Is it possible to cancel filter execution?

34- What type of filter does OutputCacheAttribute class represents?

35- What are the 2 popular asp.net mvc view engines?
36- What symbol would you use to denote, the start of a code block in razor views?

37-What symbol would you use to denote, the start of a code block in aspx views?

38- In razor syntax, what is the escape sequence character for @ symbol?

39- When using razor views, do you have to take any special steps to proctect your asp.net mvc application from cross site scripting (XSS) attacks?

40- What is asp.net master pages equivalent, when using razor views?

41- What are sections?

42- What are the file extensions for razor views?

43- How do you specify comments using razor syntax?

44-What's the deal with values parameter in ASP.NET MVC?

45- What website hosting is good for ASP.NET MVC?

46- What is Area in Asp.Net MVC projects and how to implement area in ASP.Net Projects/

47- How to Use Session in ASP.Net mVC Projects?

48- How to persist data from one page to another page in ASP.Net application?

49- What is Tempdata?

50- What is JSON?

51-What is Lambda Expression?

Comment: Nice questions. Also i have created a complete article dedicated to MVC interviews with answers here's the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556995/MVC-Interview-questions-with-answers

Answer (score 5):

Any one who reads a good MVC book or MVC 101 just before the interview can pretty much answer questions like what is MVC, describe it etc.. A sure shot way of determining if they have any working knowledge of MVC is to ask them, to lay out steps in order of how they would approach a web application using MVC. For example : Do they say, they will lay out models first? or views? and why? Do they work on Controllers first? just basic flow of a typical application. A candidate who describes this process in order and gives reasons to why it is the way it is, etc.. will be a winner you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

What is MVC?

Comment: No, that's not a relevant question to ask a prospective employee at all!

Comment: People likely didn't get that your answer is the question for the interviewer, not a question to the OP. Maybe expand it a bit for clarity?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable place to start to me.

Comment: I thought you were going to go for, "Do you like pony's and why is ASP.NET MVC a must?"

Comment: Awful,  really?   How much can you pay me if I answer what MVC is?

Answer (score 4):

Are you hiring a contractor for a short term project?

If the answer is no, I don't think MVC should really factor into the scenario.  You should almost never expect a non hired-gun employee to just drop in and be productive.  Truthfully, MVC isn't exactly a difficult learning curve.  If you are hiring someone for the long term, and their first project just happens to be an MVC site, I think you are much better served judging their general aptitude, not so much a specific technology.

Instead, see what they understand of design patterns.  MVC isnt exactly a new methodology.  If the person is able to comprehend SOC, they should easily be able to learn the specifics of MVC.  Hell, they probably could learn it on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Ask them to make a couple of substantial (but simple) changes to an existing MVC site.

This will allow you to watch how familiar they are with the organization of an MVC site. If you ask them to make an HTML change, do they go straight to the Views folder? If your change is in business logic, do they go straight to the controller action?

Sounds a bit obvious, I realize. But if they hesitate with these things, it means they haven't actually spent much time in MVC. You're testing for speed, really.

Answer (score 1):

tell him to draw the flow of the ASP.NET MVC model on the writeboard

Comment: doesn't tell you if the person is a good programmer or not. Only that he read and remembered the same book as you.

Answer (score 1):

It is funny. I asked a close question just the other day. Check out if you find something useful there.

[Can asking a developer whether he prefers WebForms or MVC be a good indicator of his proficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860057/can-asking-a-developer-whether-he-prefers-webforms-or-mvc-be-a-good-indicator-of)

Comment: Opinions are like a**holes. Everyone has got one :) But if he can back up his opinion with some decent rational logic then hire him no matter what he chooses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is not necessarily in a question, but in their portfolio. Take a look at an application they have built and question them directly on the application. Why this, why that? That way you can get a good understanding on the way they develop. Hopefully they understand the framework and the separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask them: How Asp.net MVC Is helpful in making Search Engine friendly websites?
How Routings work in .net MVC?, What is the role of ViewEngine in asp.net, can we use customize viewengine if yes then how? How can we make controller classes without suffixing "Contrller" in the class name?

Answer (score 0):

I use timer in datalist for countdown and its value display in label.

But my question is its not proper update time in datalist and when I refresh page so its get update